# Creating different size modals with angularstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-strap

I'm using angularstrap for modal boxes and something I've noticed is that the template does not have the parent .modal container. Which leads me to my question. How do I style different modal boxes differently (including size) when I do not have access to adding a class or id for that modal box wrapper?

It seems that I can only style the classes that already exist which means all my styles apply to every single modal box which is not good when I have different modal boxes that are completely different in style.

Angularjs

```
   <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      <h3>Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn" ng-click="dismiss()">Close</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="modal.saved=true;dismiss()">Save changes</button>
    </div>
```

Bootstrap example:

```
<div class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Angularstrap modal section here: [LINK](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals)

Comment: I ended up removing angularstrap modal box because it injects a new modal box into your page based on the number of times you call the same modal box so obviously if you you call it every time you list a thumbnail eventually you exceed the call stack size.

On top of not being able to create individually sized modal boxes (as described above). These are two problems that lead me to instead choose another alternative.

Answer (score 2):

While recently working on a project, to add some custom css, I added a ng-class to the existing modal-dialog box in the template

```
 <div class="modal-dialog" ng-class="{'wide-modal':modal.wide === true}">
```

and then added some css for the custom class

```
.wide-modal {
     width: 85%;
}
```

and then whenever I launched a modal and wanted my custom size modal, I added a variable to the scope

```
modal.wide = true;
```

**Scroll Bars in Modal**

In case my modal content was too much for the modal, so I added scrolling by adding this css to .modal body

```
.modal-body {
    max-height: 420px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: The problem is if you need to make the modal larger margin-left needs to be modified which exists on the parent modal class and keeps the modal centered. After running into other problems with angularstrap I replaced it with angular ui.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by creating a jquery modification to the parent of an element contained within the modal on each load of the controller. That way I could target each generic modal when it's controller was loaded via an element inside the modal like :

```
setTimeout(function(){
      $('#login').parent().css({
        "width":"562px",
        "margin-left":"-281px",
        "overflow":"auto",
        "border-radius":"7px"
      });
    },50);
```

It is in a timeout to give angular time to load the dom. Any other solution I could think of would involve modifying the bootstrap ui library. It should really let you pass in a class or ID to the modal, but this works.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Maybe because I am loading from an HTML template rather than within the body HTML.